# R shiny with plotly: invalidation still occurring inside isolate and observeEvent

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

Consider a simple plotly scatterplot that is dependent on a user selection (via `selectInput`) that selects the variable to plot on a particular axis. We want to update the plot with the click of a button, rather than when the user interacts with the `selectInput`. So, we wrap the plot-update logic in an `observeEvent` that takes a dependency on the button. The `observeEvent` updates a `reactiveValues` object that contains the plot. (This example uses `reactiveValues` because we're demonstrating this with both ggplot and plotly plots.)

When the app is run, before clicking the `actionButton`, changing the selected variable from `selectInput` does not update the plot (as expected). However, after the `actionButton` has been clicked once, any further change to the `selectInput` invalidates the plotly plot instantly and causes it to re-render. This behaviour does not occur with the ggplot plot (which only updates when the `actionButton` is clicked).

I've also tried wrapping the reactive value that defines the plotly plot in `isolate`, and create an explicit dependency on the `input$update_plts` button, but that makes no difference.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ui <- {
    fluidPage(
        selectInput('select_xvar', label = 'select x var', choices = names(mtcars)),
        actionButton('update_plts', 'Update plots'),
        plotOutput('plt1'),
        plotlyOutput('plt2')
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    val <- reactiveValues(
        plt1 = ggplot(mtcars) +
            geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)
        ),
        plt2 = plot_ly(mtcars,
            x = ~wt,
            y = ~mpg
        )
    )
    
    observeEvent(input$update_plts, {
        val$plt1 = ggplot(mtcars) +
            geom_point(aes_string(
                x = input$select_xvar,
                y = 'mpg'
            ))
        val$plt2 = plot_ly(mtcars,
            x = ~get(input$select_xvar),
            y = ~mpg)
    })
    
    output$plt1 <- renderPlot(val$plt1)

    # initial attempt with no isolate
    # output$pl2 <- renderPlotly(val$plt2)

    # second attempt with isolate, still invalidates instantaneously
    output$plt2 <- renderPlotly({
        input$update_plts
        isolate(val$plt2)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any ideas why this is the case with plotly? The only reference to this I could find is a [closed Github issue that is apparently unresolved.](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/615)

- R version 3.6.0
- plotly version 4.9.2.1
- shiny version 1.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why, but it works as expected when you `isolate` inputs in the `plot_ly` call:

```
val$plt2 = plot_ly(mtcars,
                   x = ~get(isolate(input$select_xvar)),
                   y = ~mpg)
```

You can then remove `isolate` and `actionButton` from `renderPlotly`:

```
output$plt2 <- renderPlotly(val$plt2)
```